# How to apply a nonlinear regression within a data subset from a long data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, non-linear-regression, nls

I have a data frame with several results from different experiments. I'd like to fit the data from each experiment separately to an specific function, however, my R knowledge is very shallow. Any help?

In the following MWE, the start values of the parameters are for the `ex1` data

```
ex <- c(rep("ex1", times=4), rep("ex2", times=4))
x <- rep(c(0,60,120,240), times = 2)
y <- c(0,3.73,3.08,4.07,0,1.4,2.6,2.6)

df <- data.frame(ex, x, y)

m <- nls(formula = y ~ ((a^2)*b*x)/(1+(a*b*x)),
         data = df,
         start = list(a=4.071, b=0.0253))
```

Starting values:

For ex1: `a = 4.071`, `b = 0.0253`

For ex2: `a = 2.584`, `b = 0.0155`

Comment: I'm not sure this is reproducible (singular gradient). However, I believe what you are trying to do can be accomplished via `split` and then `lapply`. For example, with a simple linear model: 
`list_of_experiments <- split(df, ex)` and then `lapply(list_of_experiments, function(df) lm(y ~ x, data = df))`

Comment: @JasonAizkalns I'm very sorry, I've posted the wrong data frame. I edited the original post. Separately, ex1 and ex2 run without problem, but when I use your trick, I get singular gradient. I need to change the start values for each experiment

Answer (score 3):

**1) One nls using grouping** It can be done in one nls call like this:

```
fo <- y ~ ((a[ex]^2)*b[ex]*x)/(1+(a[ex]*b[ex]*x))
st <- list(a = c(4.071, 2.504), b = c(0.0253, 0.0155))

m <- nls(fo, df, start = st)
m
```

giving:

```
Nonlinear regression model
  model: y ~ ((a[ex]^2) * b[ex] * x)/(1 + (a[ex] * b[ex] * x))
   data: df
     a1      a2      b1      b2 
3.76849 3.58989 0.06521 0.00385 
 residual sum-of-squares: 0.6989

Number of iterations to convergence: 8 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 4.731e-06
```

**2) Map** or we can iterate over the groups performing a separate nls on each one. `st` is from above.

```
fo1 <- y ~ ((a^2)*b*x)/(1+(a*b*x))
st1 <- split(as.data.frame(st), levels(df$ex))

L <- Map(nls, data = split(df, df$ex), st1, MoreArgs = list(formula = fo1))
L
```

giving this list of `nls` objects:

```
$ex1
Nonlinear regression model
  model: y ~ ((a^2) * b * x)/(1 + (a * b * x))
   data: dots[[1L]][[2L]]
      a       b 
3.76848 0.06521 
 residual sum-of-squares: 0.4922

Number of iterations to convergence: 7 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 3.774e-06

$ex2
Nonlinear regression model
  model: y ~ ((a^2) * b * x)/(1 + (a * b * x))
   data: dots[[1L]][[2L]]
      a       b 
3.58989 0.00385 
 residual sum-of-squares: 0.2067

Number of iterations to convergence: 9 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 3.302e-06
```

**3) update** A third way is to first run a combined nls and then subset that for each group.  `fo1` and `st` are from above.

```
m2 <- nls(fo1, df, start = sapply(st, mean))
lvs <- levels(df$ex)
L2 <- lapply(lvs, function(lv) do.call("update", list(m2, subset = df$ex == lv)))
```

It also gives a list of `nls` objects.

**4) nlsList**  Another approach is to use nlsList in the nlme package. `st` is from above.

```
library(nlme)

fo2 <- y ~ ((a^2) * b * x)/(1 + (a * b * x)) | ex
m3 <- nlsList(fo2, df, start = sapply(st, mean))
m3
```

giving the following `nlsList` object:

```
Call:
  Model: y ~ ((a^2) * b * x)/(1 + (a * b * x)) | ex 
   Data: df 

Coefficients:
           a           b
ex1 3.768487 0.065212898
ex2 3.589892 0.003850294

Degrees of freedom: 8 total; 4 residual
Residual standard error: 0.4179985
```

### Residual sum of squares

For (1) the residual sum of squares is

```
tapply(resid(m)^2, df$ex, sum)
```

and for (2) it is:

```
sapply(L, deviance)
```

and for (3) and (4) is the same with L2 or m3 in place of L.

Comment: Thanks!!!, There is a way to get the `residual sum-of-squares` separately?

Comment: `model <- nls(fo, df, start = st)` then either: `sum(model$m$resid() ^ 2)` or `sum(summary(model)$residuals ^ 2)`

Comment: Have added a section to the answer on residual sum of squares.